# Replacing Object Stored in State does not Update View

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

You can find the pertinent code and screenshot below. As well, there's a [working demo at rnplay.org](https://rnplay.org/apps/a6WL2g)

Here's the problem in a nutshell. I have a ListView. The dates of each row are dynamic, based on a mapping to an object stored in state. When I click the *Cycle Dates* button, I replace the object `this.state.cacheTimestamps` which should update each row's date. At least that's what I expect to happen. Can anyone help me understand why that is not actually happening?

```
class SampleApp extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL']),
      cacheTimestamps: {},
      cacheLotery: [
        {'ABCD': 'Jan 1, 1970'},
        {'ABCD': 'Jan 2, 1970', 'EFGH': 'Jan 2, 1971'},
        {'ABCD': 'Jan 3, 1970', 'EFGH': 'Jan 3, 1971', 'IJKL': 'Jan 3, 1972'},
      ],
    }

    // this.randomIntBetween.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({
       cacheTimestamps: this.state.cacheLotery[this.randomIntBetween(0,2)]
     })
  }

  row( id ){
    let lastCached = (this.state.cacheTimestamps[id]) ? this.state.cacheTimestamps[id] : 'never';

     return(
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.label}>
            {id}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.cache}>
            {lastCached}
          </Text>
        </View>
     )
  }

  cycleDates(){
    const min = 0;
    const max = 2;
    const idx = this.randomIntBetween(min,max);

    this.setState({
      cacheTimestamps: this.state.cacheLotery[ idx ]
    }, ()=> console.log('dbug cycleDates, new index [%i] and cacheTimestamps Object is %O', idx, this.state.cacheTimestamps));
  }

  randomIntBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.row.bind(this)} 
        />
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={ ()=>this.cycleDates() } >
          <Text style={styles.buttonTxt}>
            Cycle Dates
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Incidentally, thinking that maybe it didn't see the new object as a different object, I tried `Object.assign` as well to ensure it's a completely new object..

```
  cycleDates(){
    const min = 0;
    const max = 2;
    const idx = this.randomIntBetween(min,max);

    this.setState({
      cacheTimestamps: Object.assign({}, this.state.cacheLotery[ idx ])
    }, ()=> console.log('dbug cycleDates, new index [%i] and cacheTimestamps Object is %O', idx, this.state.cacheTimestamps));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

When updating setState, I needed to also update the dataSource. The [Working Demo at RNPlay](https://rnplay.org/apps/a6WL2g) has also been updated.

```
  cycleDates(){
    const min = 0;
    const max = 3;
    const idx = this.randomIntBetween(min,max);

    this.setState({
      cacheTimestamps: this.state.cacheLotery[ idx ],
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(['ABCD','EFGH','IJKL']),
    }, ()=> console.log('dbug cycleDates, new index [%i] and cacheTimestamps Object is %O', idx, this.state.cacheTimestamps));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to renderRow in ListView and pass this.state.cacheTimestamps as a prop.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      timeStamps={this.state.cacheTimestamps} 
  />
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={ ()=>this.cycleDates() } >
  <Text style={styles.buttonTxt}>
    Cycle Dates
    </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: Stephens - Thank you for your response, but I don't understand your suggestion. In your  example, you removed the renderRow function which I assume was a mistake, but then add the timeStamps presumably to pass in a `this.props.timeStamps` variable into the renderRow function, but when I `console.log(this.props)` within the renderRow function, it returns an object with value `{rootTag: 1}`. Would you please fork the rnplay link and provide a working sample to demonstrate your suggestion?

Comment: Well, you said it was not specific to React-Native but ListView is specific to React-Native. I was treating it as ListView being one of your components that could be edited and the renderRow put there. I haven't tried React-Native yet.

Comment: Ah, okay... well sorry. I may have been wrong about about it being a generic react issue. I assumed that passing an object around in react would be the same regardless. Thanks for your time.

Comment: By the way I think the issue is that state updates effect the render. ie. your row(id) method won't know about state changes.

Comment: I just found and posted the solution, which was to update the dataSource as well as the object reference. Thanks again!